# Array.pop in Node skips and forgets a function item

Tags: javascript, node.js

I had an idea to store code as lists (arrays) in Node and execute them, but this is harder than I thought: if I make a list with a function in the beginning or in the end, `.pop` or `.shift` removes but omits it and returns the next element:

```
> l = [1, 75, 84, function() { console.log('aseuht') }]
[ 1, 75, 84, [Function] ]
> l.pop()
84
> l
[ 1, 75 ]
```

I noticed this in Node v0.4.9, but it is still present in 0.6.10.

Is there a workaround for that?

**update:** I filed an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2773).

**update 2:** the bug is present only in my shell, when I run these commands from a standalone script, it works correctly. So this is just a shell issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried it in Node, Firefox, and Chrome and it worked as expected in all three.

here's the code I used:

```
var l= [1, 75, 84, function() { console.log('aseuht'); }];
console.log(l);
console.log(l.pop());
console.log(l);
```

and result:

```
[ 1, 75, 84, [Function] ]
[Function]
[ 1, 75, 84 ]
```

and the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5M8M/

What version of Node are you using?

Comment: So you cut and pasted the code snippet I wrote and it did not work as mine did? I don't understand why we're seeing different things.

Comment: Wow, we're bug finders! Well, you are... ha. I'd say that's an accomplishment.